# Mac won't connect to localhost server run from VirtualBox

Tags: macos, server, localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

My mac won't connect to localhost, I've tried with Safari and Mozilla, so it's not the browser, I tried other solutions I found on the internet, I ping 127.0.0.1 and it works correctly, if I run `dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost` I get the following:

```
name: localhost
ipv6_address: ::1

name: localhost
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

If I run `apachectl configtest` I get `Syntax OK`.

I've also read that my /etc/hosts might have been corrupted, this is how it looks like:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I have no idea what else to try

EDIT: I'm trying to run an application (Hortonworks Sandbox) from a virtual machine (VirtualBox) in mac, I was advised to try port forwarding but this is what I see when I check the port forwarding in VirtualBox, seems like everything is in order:

[image]

I also tried to run Vagrant from VirtualBox and Mac couldn't connect to the localhost server when needed

Comment: What port is your service running on? Do you use non default port? e.g. if ssh is running on port 4322 and you don't specify it -> it won't work because by default 22 is used

Comment: @MarekH I'm trying to run several things that require connection through localhost, one of the ports was 1080 (hortonworks sandbox), other was 8080 (vagrant), none of them works for their respective applications, I never got to make this mac connect to a localhost server

Comment: you run them through docker, not locally correct? You need port forwarding

Comment: I run them through virtualbox, that might be the issue then, I'm going to check how to do port forwarding

Comment: I check the virtualbox configured virtual machine port forwarding and there are many rules that connect different host ports to guest ports through host ip 127.0.0.1. I guess it's not something I can fix from the virtualbox end then and I cannot find information on how to do it in mac

Comment: e.g. some tutorial like this. Try to setup ssh (to test if it works) installing ssh server part need to match your system (its easy)  https://medium.com/platform-engineer/port-forwarding-for-ssh-http-on-virtualbox-459277a888be

Comment: I cannot set any of those 2 rules because I always get this message: 'The current port forwarding rules are not valid. Few rules have the same ports and conflicting IP addresses'. Also, seems like there are SSH rules already set like in that tutorial (the machine is supposedly already configured to overcome this so that's why it has many rules already set)

Comment: Can you connect to ssh inside the virtualbox? Do you see any ssh port listed? Don't say 22 (it will connect you to local installation, not virtualbox).

Comment: The virtual machine itself is just like a server, like you cannot do anything with it, you just start it and you are supposed to be able to access the server through your localhost but I'm not able to interact with the virtual machine itself, it's just a black screen telling me to connect through the localhost in my machine

Comment: If I check the virtualbox configuration for that machine in particular it says that the SSH host port is 2212 and the guest port is 22, should I change the guest port?

Comment: What's the IP address of the server. Run ifconfig command. And don't tell me 127.0.0.1

Comment: you should be able to connect using "ssh username@localhost -p 2212" ssh server has to work. Also try within virtual machine with port 22

Comment: when I try that it says 'connection refused'

Comment: This is too troublesome. You haven't even written if you used port 22 or 2212, which user you tried to connect with etc. You are not trying and hoping I solve it for you. This method you won't learn what you are doing.